# android - fc without an obvious reason

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code. On my 3 different devices it works totally fine but a lot of my app users are reporting fc when this activity starts

Logcat from every one of then is saying NullPointerException in onCreate

Code:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/E3WyeYdN)

And this is how i start this activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this,ProfileEditor.class);
    intent.putExtra("profileName","");//this is when creating new profile, when editing profile name goes here
    startActivityForResult(intent,GET_CODE);
```

Comment: what line in the onCreate method is the error occurring? (post your logcat)

Comment: Paste the logcat please otherwise, how do we know which line causes the exception. My guess is profile = db.getProfileByName(profileName);

Comment: Posting logcat in first post...

Comment: I cant find it right now let me check with one of my users

Comment: its line 678. I cant post logcat because since that logcat i have changed code a litle but i just looked at my git and compared it to logcat and in current file its line 678. Sorry for complicating things, but i cant find anyone to provide me with logcat right now